# AS/400 ODBC Drivers

Tags: odbc, ibm-midrange

We have been using the Client Access ODBC drivers when accessing AS/400 data from our .net applications and SQL DTS/SSIS packages. Are there third party drivers that provide better performance or functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Our company is using the same Client Access drivers. As far as we know there are no other ones available. One issue we ran into last year was that there were no 64-bit drivers available so our servers that have applications connecting to the AS/400 must be 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is on the other side of the hill, but I've been using [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) as a JDBC (well, Java ...) driver in a previous project. This is an OpenSource version of the [IBM Toolbox for Java](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/). As such it is usually some versions ahead of the IBM release and had fewer bugs. My experience with this driver was very positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows built-in drivers to connect, but my guess is the the IBM driver would be faster.

Are you seeing a performance hit or are you just trying to squeeze out more performance? If it is the first one, look at your system to see if it is sized properly. At an old job, the system was sized too small for what we where using it for. Some simple queries took minutes to run. If it is the latter, maybe try adding some more RAM to the System i.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's better performance but a quick google turns up [Hit ODBC/400](http://www.hitsw.com/products_services/sql400/odbc400/odbc400.html).

Answer (score 0):

IBM has been consolidating their DB2 drivers, so the universal DB2 driver should be able to connect to DB2/400.

I have not tried it yet though.  I'd like to hear experiences.